# How can AnotherActivity extend MainActivity

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm trying to make my `AnotherActivity` extend main `FullscreenActivity`, but I'm geting error, that there is no empty constructor

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.terrh/com.example.terrh.FullscreenActivity$AnotherActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.terrh.FullscreenActivity$AnotherActivity; no empty constructor
```

so I've tried to add it, but not correctly.

**FulscreenActivity.java**

```
public class FullscreenActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ihkj);
    }

    public void buttonClicked(View button) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public class AnotherActivity extends FullscreenActivity {
        public AnotherActivity() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.another);
        }    
    }
}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.terrh.FullscreenActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.terrh.FullscreenActivity$AnotherActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <intent-filter >
            <action  android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.AnotherActivity"/>
            <category  android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

How can I add empty constructor properly to get this working or can I solve this problem in another way?

Comment: Not quite sure why you need this. But according to you, you may need to create an empty constructor in MainActivity. But I am not quite sure :-) . Check if it works

Comment: Well, I need this to reduce the amount of .class files in src. That is my question, I don't know ho to add that empty constructor (pretty stupid quetsion i guess :D)

Comment: try adding "MainActivity(){//}" in MainActivity

Comment: @Nabin sorry dude i thought to remove title bar(fullscreenactivity)

Comment: @user3860990 I think you don't even know what you want :-)

Comment: I think it just shouldn't be an inner extending Activity and stuff, that doesn't really seem to have any kind of purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first is you cant create default constructor when extend Activity there are no need. if you want to get public functions of anotherActivity class then create static method getInstance() of that class. see below code:

```
public static Activity activity;

public void onCreate (...){
   ....
   ....
  activity=anotherActivity.this;
}

public static anotherActivity getInstance(){
   return activity;
}
```

thats it..